# AndroidPdfViewer Library

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

I found [Barteksc library](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) for showing PDF files inside my activity. I tried to use sample code but it failed. My code did not loaded the PDF File from asset folder.

Here is my Main Activity code:

```
package ir.diamonddesign.pdfviewer;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
        int REQUEST_CODE = 42;

        String SAMPLE_FILE = "zan.pdf";
        PDFView pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        Integer pageNumber = 0;
        String pdfFileName;

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

        pdfView.fromAsset("zan.pdf");

    }
}
```

This is my Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ir.diamonddesign.pdfviewer.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="salam donya !" />

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What can be the possible solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just missing `.load()` which require to load pdf.

Your code should look like : `pdfView.fromAsset("zan.pdf").load();`

Comment: not working on me ? even if the permissions are good, its not working > api 23